# VB.NET Regular Expressions - and _

Tags: regex, vb.net

I'm trying to parse letters, numbers and - and _ from a URL. \w*\d* gets it close but I can't figure out how parse out the - (minus) and the _ (underscore). Can someone help me out? My knowledge is limited.

An example is: BSZVVDdBj-s or BSZxkx_hjFa

For all I know a - and _ may be in the same letters and numbers as well.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To get letters, numbers, underscore and hyphens, use:

```
^[\w-]+$
```

- `\w` denotes a word character (includes `A-Z`, `a-z`, `0-9` and `_`)
- `-` allows hyphen
- `[\w-]` represents a character class which allows a letter, number, hyphen or underscore
- `[\w-]+` has the `+` to denote one or more characters
- `^` and `$` denote starting and ending anchors

Or if you are trying to get matches within a larger string, get rid of the anchor tags, like this:

```
[\w-]+
```

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/I5u7H9/1/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for explaining all it. But it returns 0 when I use it. I was really hoping that'd be it since it's so technical. Is there any else I can provide that may be useful?

Comment: Did you try the second one? Just `[\w-]+`?

Comment: Here's an example of the URL: https://web.stagram.com/p/BSZVVDdBj-s and https://web.stagram.com/p/BSZxkx_hjFa

Comment: yes i did but i didn't work. It returned 6,122. Not 945. How can I use that regex demo?

Comment: Browse the demo link, in the text area paste what should match and what shouldn't match. Then check if it gets highlighted or not. Once you have examples of how the regex is failing you can point those out or try to improve the regex.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: @NeilSiegfried If you want the last part of the URL then `theUrl.Substring(theUrl.LastIndexOf("/"c) + 1)` gets that.

Comment: I think I missed the point that you are simply trying to get the last part of the URL. You should consider following what @AndrewMorton has mentioned instead of regex.

Comment: @NeilSiegfried If you still want to try to do it using regex instead of the recommended substring solution, you can try `(?<=\/)[\w-]+(?=\s)`